# How to fix "Database (database.sqlite) does not exist." in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, laravel, laravel-5

I'm studying laravel then I switched mysql from sqlite. I deleted the database.sqlite file, configure the database.php to mysql and .env file.

I'm having a error "Database (database.sqlite) does not exist". How to fix this error?

Comment: Please show contents of `.env` and `/config/database.php` files

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I think Im connected but I have another error it says "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: users (SQL: select * from "users")"

Comment: Run `php artisan migrate` command, it will create `users` table

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sqlite driver doesn't create the database file if it doesn't exist.

The simple solution is to create an empty file just before migrating the database into it (filling the file with schemas and data)

Simply put, this command will fix it:

```
 touch database/database.sqlite
```

Comment: this is not working for me

Answer (score 2):

You don't need anything in the .env file except the DB_CONNECTION key/value pair. When you are using SQLite, remove all of the following keys:

DB_HOST

DB_PORT

DB_DATABASE

DB_USERNAME

DB_PASSWORD

Comment: Can you explain further how this fixes the problem of a non-existing file?

Comment: In my case the **file exists**, and the proposed solution did not work for me. This is the solution that worked for me that I posted.

Comment: I've spent the last few hours trying to get MySQL, PostgreSQL and then Sqlite to work. Following this and removing the other items from the .ENV file is what actually worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the above solution can not handle the current issue. click here

[Issue with SQLite and Laravel on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68409835/5659868)