# Laravel - Heroku - SQLite - database does not exists

Tags: laravel, heroku, laravel-5

I have `laravelproject/database/database.sqlite`

It works on **local** but on **heroku** got error `Database (/app/database/database.sqlite) does not exist.`

I use default **database.php** of L5.5 **connections.sqlite.database** `env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite'))`

Answer (score 2):

you not update your database.sqlite i had the same problem try this.

```
git add -f database/database.sqlite
```

then push to heroku

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Following documentation update from Heroku relationship with Laravel.

You should try the following.

```
"ext-pdo_sqlite": "*"
```

Add to composer.json file and run the composer update command

```
composer update
```

After this, deploy to Heroku and test your app once again.